# Python Pandas: String Contains and Doesn't Contain

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to match rows of a Pandas DataFrame that contains and doesn't contain certain strings. For example:

```
import pandas
df = pandas.Series(['ab1', 'ab2', 'b2', 'c3'])
df[df.str.contains("b")]
```

Output:

```
0    ab1
1    ab2
2     b2
dtype: object
```

Desired output:

```
2     b2
dtype: object
```

Question: is there an elegant way of saying something like this?

```
df[[df.str.contains("b")==True] and [df.str.contains("a")==False]]
# Doesn't give desired outcome
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're almost there, you just haven't got the syntax quite right, it should be:

```
df[(df.str.contains("b") == True) & (df.str.contains("a") == False)]
```

Another approach which might be cleaner if you have a lot of conditions to apply would to be to chain your filters together with reduce or a loop:

```
from functools import reduce
filters = [("a", False), ("b", True)]
reduce(lambda df, f: df[df.str.contains(f[0]) == f[1]], filters, df)
#outputs b2
```

Comment: Don't need to use == True and can use the complement operator tilda `~` instead of == False

Answer (score 9):

Either:

```
>>> ts.str.contains('b') & ~ts.str.contains('a')
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```

or use regex:

```
>>> ts.str.contains('^[^a]*b[^a]*$')
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use .loc and ~ to index:

```
df.loc[(df.str.contains("b")) & (~df.str.contains("a"))]

2    b2
dtype: object
```